# Is it possible to get customDimensions["--"] dynamic Properties in application insight? Can we write loop in kusto Queries

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I need to loop through the customDimensions.

example: I have scenario like 1000 tags(json objects) inside the customDimensions like below

cust_0: array
cust_1: array

like 1000 tags inside the customDimensions I want to iterate through and get the JSON object is it possible loop in kusto queries?

sample data: As given sample data I stored below in customDimensions like that i have multiple rows, and in that, I want to combine(merge) the array0, array1, array2  how to write the query to merge the records array0 array1 array2 are dynamically generated columns

{ 
   "sample1":"data",
   "sample2":"data",
   "sample3":"data",
   "sample4":"daa",
   "sample5":"data",
   "sample6":"data",
   "array0":[ 
      { 
         "1":"0",
         "2":"1",
         "3":"1",
         "4":"1 1",
         "5":"1 1",
         "6":"",
         "7":"",
         "8":"1(1)",
         "9":"1",
         "10":"1"
      },
      "array1":      [ 
         { 
            "1":"0",
            "2":"1",
            "3":"1",
            "4":"1 1",
            "5":"1 1",
            "6":"",
            "7":"",
            "8":"1(1)",
            "9":"1",
            "10":"1"
         }
      ]
   },

}
{ 
   "sample1":"data",
   "sample2":"data",
   "sample3":"data",
   "sample4":"daa",
   "sample5":"data",
   "sample6":"data",
   "array0":[ 
      { 
         "1":"0",
         "2":"1",
         "3":"1",
         "4":"1 1",
         "5":"1 1",
         "6":"",
         "7":"",
         "8":"1(1)",
         "9":"1",
         "10":"1"
      },
      "array1":      [ 
         { 
            "1":"0",
            "2":"1",
            "3":"1",
            "4":"1 1",
            "5":"1 1",
            "6":"",
            "7":"",
            "8":"1(1)",
            "9":"1",
            "10":"1"
         }
      ]
   },

}

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to achieve that using `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`.

if you're not sure how, please provide a sample data set (preferably, using the `datatable` operator), and the expected output for it, with a verbal description of the logic you want to implement

Comment: added sample code is it possible to write the query for that

Comment: (1) you said you want to merge array0, array1 and array2. what is array2 in your sample data set? (2) your "arrays" have a single element, which is a property bag. is that actually how your data is constructed, and you actually want to iterate over the key-value pairs in these property bags in the single-member arrays? (3) for the sample data set you've provided - what is the expected output? i.e. what does "merge" mean in your terminology, specifically when items repeat in multiple arrays/property bags?

Comment: 1) my object constructed like that inside of object I have array0 array1 like multiple arrays inside the object.

Comment: 2) inside of my array I have multiple properties I had given sample. No i don't want to iterate inside array but i want to combine the arrays of same or different objects and make single object or array.3) I want to get the final output as combining all the array of multiple and same object to single array or object